# How to watch which php files have been executed within a period of time?

Tags: php, windows-server

Some website article pictures often be deleted. I want a tool can watch which php files have been executed within a period of time.

The envirment is apache+mysql on windows server2008 R2

Comment: Apache access_log registers every access to a specific URL. It could help

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says this question is off topic here.

Comment: @Humba Thanks :)

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks :) I will read it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to get the file name:

```
 $fname=   $_SERVER["SCRIPT_FILENAME"];
```

or

```
$fname=  basename(__FILE__, '.php'); //without extension
```

and use this to log it to a file :

```
$logfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = $fname;
fwrite($logfile, $txt);
$ts=time();
fwrite($logfile, $ts);
fclose($logfile);
```

you can wrap it in a function and call it in the beginning of each php file.